# Print one word from a list within a dictionary (python)

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, random

I want my program to print only one random word from the list within my dictionary, but I can't seem to get the right syntax to do so. I attempted using popitem() to get a random value from the list, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
import random

thesaurus = {
              "happy":["glad",  "blissful", "ecstatic", "at ease"],
              "sad"  :["bleak", "blue", "depressed"]
            }

# input
phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")

# turn input into list
part1 = phrase.split()
part2 = list(part1)

newlist = [] 
for x in part2:
    s = thesaurus.get(x, x)
    newlist.append(s)

print (newlist)
```

For example, if the input is

```
i am happy
```

The expected output would be

```
i am glad
```

or any random word from the list within the dictionary.

But, right now my output looks like this:

```
['i', 'am', ['glad', 'blissful', 'ecstatic', 'at ease']]
```

I know there is another thread involved with this, but it doesn't seem to address this specific issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

edit:

If I extended this formula to work with an imported file with a long list of words, how would I have to change the code?

```
newDict = {}
with open('thesaurus.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split()
        newDict[(splitLine[0])] = ",".join(splitLine[1:])

print ("Total words in thesaurus: ", len(newDict))

# input
phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")

# turn input into list
part1 = phrase.split()
part2 = list(part1)

# testing input
newlist = []
for x in part2:
    s = newDict[x].pop() if x in newDict else x
    s = random.choice(newDict[x]).upper() if x in newDict else x
    newlist.append(s)


newphrase = ' '.join(newlist)
print (newphrase)
```

sample of line text within the "thesaurus" file:

```
abash,humility,fear
```

Comment: What you mean by `thesaurus.get(x, x)` ?

Comment: @Arman the second `x` is a default value. The statement essentially means "Get the value associated with key `x` or just return `x` if no value is found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to make use of the [**random**](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/random.html) module:

Example:

```
import random
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> random.choice(l)
5
>>> random.choice(l)
9
```

In your case, you could do:

```
print (" ".join(random.choice(thesaurus[x]) if x in thesaurus else x for x in part2))
```

Example:

```
>>> import random
>>> phrase = "I am feeling sad that he left, but that's okay because I'm happy he will be back soon"
>>>
>>> thesaurus = { "happy":["glad",  "blissful", "ecstatic", "at ease"],
...               "sad"  :["bleak", "blue", "depressed"]
...             }
>>> print (" ".join(random.choice(thesaurus[x]) if x in thesaurus else x for x in phrase.split()))
I am feeling bleak that he left, but that's okay because I'm blissful he will be back soon
```

Comment: Thanks! If I extended this formula to work with an imported file with a long list of words, how would I have to change the code you posted above? I edited the original post to show the extended code, any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
 thesaurus.get(x,x)
```

means `thesaurus[x] if x in thesaurus else x`

since `thesaurus["happy"]` is a list it returns the whole list

I think you want to just get a single item

```
for x in part2:
   s = thesaurus[x].pop() if x in thesaurus else x # returns first word (and removes from list)
   s = thesaurus[x][0] if x in thesaurus else x # returns first word without removing it
   s = random.choice(thesaurus[x])if x in thesaurus else x # returns random word
   newlist.append(s)
```

Comment: This would shrink the list, no? That doesn't seem to be appropriate.

Comment: he said he tried "popitem" so i thought maybe it was

Comment: Thanks! If I extended this formula to work with an imported file with a long list of words, how would I have to change the code you posted above? I edited the original post to show the extended code, any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) your output to this.  You can join the list together to form a string of you want too.

```
newList= list(map(lambda x:  random.choice(x) if type(x) == list else x, newList))

print(" ".join(newList))
```

Comment: `type(x)` is in general not a good way to type check ... it is much preferred to use `isinstance`, this has the additional problem of having to re iter through the list, effectivly doubling the time complexity (probably isnt much of an issue) ...

Comment: Can someone edit my post to format it correctly? :( not sure how to do it on mobile.

Comment: since it works and you wrote it on mobile ill give +1 though :P

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not modify your original dictionary

```
for x in part2:
    s = random.choice(thesaurus.get(x, [x]))
    newlist.append(s)
```

Your dictionary maps a string to list of strings, therefore your original solution puts a list in the place of a string. `random.choice` chooses a random element from the list.